# node-sass CLI order of operations

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, node-sass

I am trying to make sense of using node-sass source maps, and pipe the output into another process (to use autoprefix and then cssnano to minify).

Currently I have gotten node-sass to work with sourcemaps using the following command:

```
node-sass --source-map default.css.map input.scss output.css
```

In this order, it sees default.css.map as the output location for the source map. It then sees input.scss as the entry file and output.css as the built file.

What I would like to have work is to pipe the output to another process, i.e.:

```
node-sass --source-map default.css.map input.scss | (use another module to run another build step)
```

When I omit the output file however, it uses the map file as the input file, and input.scss as the output. I tried putting the entry file before the source-map option, but that didn't seem to work.

Is there something I should know here that I'm missing? Can anyone offer some help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually working fine, and it is the subsequent process that breaks it. This is an issue of getting

```
postcss -u autoprefixer
```

to skip the css map.